# Clean classloader from timerTask connectionpool

Tags: classloader

i have an application with some timertask, connectionPools. I also developpe a classloader and sometime i need to clean the classloader. The problem is that the timer task is like a daemon with refere to a class. How can i cancel the timers from the timertask and how can i close connection pools without calling to the .remove() but using a general solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you load a class via a classloader, there is no direct method to unload the class from that classloader.

Can you describe the question in more details?